# python script runs MongoClient but not with Apache

Tags: python-3.x, apache, pymongo

I've installed all the requirements to work with pymongo+apache+python... but for some reason when i run this from the webbrowser it reports in the error log 
but it works fine from the shell with a normal ./script.py

If i comment the from pymongo.... it runs ok with the browser.
Any clues?

> [client ::1:60818] End of script output before headers: index.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cgitb
from pymongo import MongoClient
from structures import Structures

cgitb.enable()

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("""hello mundo!")
```